# Jenkins pipeline: groovy: Capture specific log in Output

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Since the [text finder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin) isn't supporting pipelines we don't see another solution then writing some groovy function which will capture our Jenkins output log and search on the string which will come as parameter.

We use declarative pipelines and use managed shared libraries so we can reuse that function.

If there is a match we want to make the build unstable.

This is what we have now (this script is called in our pipeline with the job_name (test) and a string).

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def call(String jobname, String build_string) {
  echo "Hello, ${jobname}."

  def job = Jenkins.instance.items.find { it.name == jobname }
    for (build in job.builds) {
        def log = build.log
        if (log.contains(build_string)) {
            println "${job.name}: ${build.id}"
        }
    }
}

It fails at:
Hello, test.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: builds for class: java.lang.Boolean
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
```

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: Under pipeline-syntax/globals you can see, that the manager-variables. It allows you to analyse the log by using manager.logContains(regexp) or manager.getLogMatcher(regexp). have you tried those functions?

Comment: Interesting, I'll take a look, thanks

Comment: Do yo know if I can use it without using 'manager'. This works only with certain groovy plugins but no the ones I'm using.

Comment: i don't think it will work without those plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You might need

```
import hudson.model.*
```

or something similar at the beginning of your pipeline script